# Why is DatePicker returning a different Value then it is showing and getting? TWO-WAY DataBinding MVVM

Tags: android-studio, mvvm, android-databinding, 2-way-object-databinding

I'm using a DatePicker where I wont to get the selected Date. I have tried to set the Data before getting it.

```
<DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/datepicker"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:calendarViewShown="false"
            android:datePickerMode="spinner"
            android:day="@={viewmodel.day}"
            android:month="@={viewmodel.month}"
            android:year="@={viewmodel.year}" />
```

I have set the DatePicker to a spinner. I'm passing every single data "Day", "Month" and "Year" to a MutableLiveData object.

```
public class DateViewModel{
    private MutableLiveData<Integer> day = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private MutableLiveData<Integer> month = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private MutableLiveData<Integer> year = new MutableLiveData<>();
}
```

I tried to initialiaz the data and it is showing me the right dates.

```
public void setDate(){
        day.setValue(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        month.setValue(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH));
        year.setValue(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
}
```

I'm trying to set the data into a Date Objekt.

```
  Date crtDate;
        Integer cYear = year != null ? year.getValue() : 0;
        Integer cMonth = month != null ? month.getValue() : 0;
        Integer cDay = day != null ? day.getValue() : 0;
        if (cDay != null && cMonth != null && cYear != null) {
            crtDate= new Date(cYear, cMonth, cDay);
            filterData.setSpinnerDate(crtDate);
        }
```

Now when i try to get the same Date back without changing anything on the spinner it gives me different results.

```
  System.out.println("-----------> Day: " + filterData.getSpinnerDate.getDay());
  System.out.println("-----------> Month: " + filterData.getSpinnerDate.getMonth());
  System.out.println("-----------> Year: " + filterData.getSpinnerDate.getYear());
```

By outputing the values it gives me different values.
Thanks in advance